# gulp-eslint not throwing any error on console

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gulp, eslint

I am working with `gulp` and `reactjs`. I have added `eslint` for static analysing of my code. I am using `gulp-eslint` as follows:

```
var eslint = require('gulp-eslint');
gulp.task('eslint', function() {
  // Process all script files, but ignore npm_modules
  gulp.src(['widgets/**/*.js', 'server/**/*.js', '!node_modules/**'])
    .pipe(eslint.format())
    .pipe(eslint.failAfterError());
```

My `.eslintrc` file is :

```
{
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
  "plugins": [
  "react"
],
"parserOptions": {
"ecmaVersion": 6,
"sourceType": "module",
"ecmaFeatures": {
  "jsx": true
}
},
"extends": ["eslint:recommended", "plugin:react/recommended"],
"env": {
"browser": true,
"amd": true,
"es6": true,
"node": true,
"mocha": true
},
"rules": {
"comma-dangle": 1,
"quotes": [ 1, "single" ],
"no-undef": 1,
"global-strict": 0,
"no-extra-semi": 1,
"no-underscore-dangle": 0,
"no-console": 1,
"no-unused-vars": 1,
"no-trailing-spaces": [1, { "skipBlankLines": true }],
"no-unreachable": 1,
"no-alert": 0,
"react/jsx-uses-react": 1,
"react/jsx-uses-vars": 1
}
}
```

But, even if i have trailing spaces and alerts in my code, it won't show any error on the console. All it does is:

```
Starting 'eslint'...
Finished 'eslint' after 1.97 s
```

The directory structure is:

```
root/
node_modules
widgets //contains the js files
server //contains the js files
.eslintrc
gulpfile.js
package.json
```

Answer (score 0):

You've forgot to pipe `estlint()` properly. Try:

```
var eslint = require('gulp-eslint');
gulp.task('eslint', function() {
  // Process all script files, but ignore npm_modules
  gulp.src(['widgets/**/*.js', 'server/**/*.js', '!node_modules/**'])
    .pipe(eslint({
      useEslintrc: true
    }))
    .pipe(eslint.format())
    .pipe(eslint.failAfterError());
```

Comment: Tried to set `useEslintrc` option explicit? I've updated my answer. Also, show please your directory structure.

Comment: Wouldn't you mind to show the directory structure by updating the question? It would be much more readable.

Comment: I've just noticed that there is `"no-alert": 0,` rule in `.eslintrc`. That means that `eslint` will allow alerts. Could you please also provide code that you try to analyse with `eslint`?

Comment: render:function() {
    var a;
    var b=10;
    alert(b);

Comment: tried tesing the above code..but didn't give warning for the unused variable

Comment: Please, update the questions. Comments are bad place to paste code :)

Comment: One more moment, do you have `babel-eslint` installed?